# Mouse over marker no longer works after right click

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WEZVX/2/

Notice when you mouse over the marker, you see an overlay showing the users name.

Then if you right click the marker to display the menu and let it close.

The mouse over overlay from before no longer displays?

Any idea why and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a tag to the context menu overlay

http://gmap3.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=229

Then calling clear on the menu only by tag.